# Use matcher to match all within a range?

Tags: java, regex

How can I use java matcher to match all the characters in the needle within a range of the haystack.
For example, if the needle is (AB), I would like to find exact matches that occur within a 5 character window. So, (ACCCB) would be a match. The 5 character substring should be a sliding window that moves through the entire haystack. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

`A.{,5}B` may be what you want. Even though im not what you mean with "The 5 character substring should be a sliding window that moves through the entire haystack".

Comment: You need `A.{0,5}B`. IIRC, you can't skip the first number.